# keeping the same file format when saving .xlsx file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Im working on a project where I have to take excel file make changes to the data and save it

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_excel("infile.xlsx")

#manuplate data 

writer = ExcelWriter('outfile.xlsx')
dfs.to_excel(writer,'Sheet5')
writer.save()
```

The problem I have is the newly saved excel file does not have the same format(cell widht, bold borders) as the input file. What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can't preserve the formatting because pandas throws away all that information upon import. You would need to specify the formatting options you want in the output with the `ExcelWriter` object. If you use the option `engine='xlsxwriter'` you can then use all the xlsxwriter formatting options before writing the final file. You can find more details in the [XlsxWriter documentation.](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

# This removes the default header style so we can override it later
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   'Data2': [90, 80, 30, 15, 88, 34, 41]})


# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Create Format objects to apply to sheet
# https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-methods-and-format-properties
red_bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})
border = workbook.add_format({'border':5, 'border_color':'blue'})

#Apply formatting to sheet
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, red_bold)
worksheet.set_column('A1:A8', None, border)

# Apply a conditional format to a cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: sounds about the right direction to the solution. By any chance, would you be able to provide code example on your answer?

Comment: Updated with an example for you.

Comment: Yes, you can set the formating for data you created on the python code. However, the problem I have is extracting the formating from .xlsx file and applying the same formating to the newly created .xlsx

Comment: Do you know how to do that?