# Pandas DataFrame: the cells are modified but the changes do not save

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner in Data Science, so please sorry if my mistake is dumb.

Here, I have a loop which views my data frame and makes changes using .loc
The problem is that the changes are not saved at the end. I checked every step, everything is processing right. I even checked the modified cell right after working on it (look below) and its gives the value I put into it. However, when the program finishes the my excel data frame is not changed at all.

Help please. Thank you in advance!

```
exc = pd.read_excel('...')

...

for x, y in exc.iterrows():
    y = y.copy() # got this row from some guy's code

    # ... a lot of conditions ...

    if check_num == check_opt:            
        exc.loc[x, 'PP'] = int(df['Docs'][every])

        print(exc.loc[x, 'PP']) # prints the new value -> int(df['Docs'][every])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the program finishes my excel data frame is not changed at all.

That's because you never wrote anything to the Excel file. With `exc = pd.read_excel('...')` you create a Python object `exc` (more specifically, a pandas DataFrame), and all the subsequent modifications happen to this object. To change the source file accordingly, you can use pandas' [`DataFrame.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method, by adding this line in the end:

```py
exc.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Instead of `output`, you can of course choose any file name you like (e.g. the name of your source file). Just be careful and keep in mind that this will overwrite any existing file by that name in your working directory.

Comment: I tried to do this and it actually worked. Thanks for the advice. But the problem is that the cells in my excel file have different sizes/colors, so if I put this `exc.to_excel("output.xlsx")` in my code they all go back to default. I hope you got it.

Comment: Yes, this is a typical problem when switching between file formats designed for different purposes. If you must have the Excel formatting, this answer has some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411809/keeping-the-same-file-format-when-saving-xlsx-file-using-python/51412330